# Cast to number in oracle

Tags: oracle, casting, oracle10g

I am trying to cast following part of the query to number but I really mess it. If I don't use :elt_day parameter it gives me correct results but when I use it :elt_day parameter it tells me ora 00932 Inconsistent Datatypes: Expected number got timestamp. I believe that I can fix problem by Cast but as I told I really mess.

```
CASE
WHEN ch.date_entered - LAG (ch.next_date) OVER (
    PARTITION BY ch.virtual_customer_id )
    ORDER BY
        ch.end_date 
) >:elt_day
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `elt_day`, and the 'date' columns on the table?

Comment: Also, what is the value you are trying to assign to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TO_NUMBER` or `CAST` oracle functions.

Hope it helps.